# Is it possible to execute function to run/call/activate at specific moment?

Tags: php, function

I wonder if possible to execute (run,call,activate..) the function, after when php detects that :

1) $something varialbe is being defined

 or

2) something other function is executed. See example:

```
function sayy()
   {
   echo "Hiiiiiii";
   }
RUN FUNCTION when $VARIALBE will be set;
......
......
......
......
......
......
include('blablabla.php');
//i dont have access to blablabla.php,and there is code:
$VARIALBE = 'Jake';
!!!!!!!!!THEN I WANT EXECUTE MY FUNCTION HERE!!!!!!!!!!!
```

Comment: How is this different than just calling the function: `sayy()`?

Comment: Typically that would be handled through a class, which has function `setVariable($value)`.  Then you can do whatever logic you want on change of the variable.

Comment: There aren't events such as "variable set" for you to attach onto. Your only hope here would be to do like mellamokb suggested and use a class. Either with a setter method as described or using the php magic method `__set` that gets called when a property is set.

Answer (score 2):

Sure:

```
function sayy($value) {
  echo "Hi.";
  return $value;
}

$VARIABLE = sayy('Jake');
```

Or in a sane, object-oriented manner, see [Why use getters and setters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters)

Basically, you set your variable to `private` and make a `public` function that sets the variable and also does whatever you want your function to do. PHP has a set of "magic functions" that will allow you to do this without specifically writing a getter/setter for every variable, eg: [`__set()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set)

Comment: i dont have access to that file, please read my question again, and edit answer. thanks

Comment: @taztodgmail then no, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle your need is to learn OOP. This a good place to start. [KillerPHP](http://www.killerphp.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php/)